# How do I copy a file from multiple servers to my local system?

Tags: scp, file-copy

We have multiple deployment of an application on servers such as app00, app01 and so on. I need to copy a single log file from all these servers onto my local mac so I can perform some grepping and cutting.

I used csshX for viewing this file but I cannot find an equivalent for scp. I basically want two things:

1. Ability to connect to n numbers of such servers and copy the file
2. Avoid naming conflicts locally perhaps by prefixing the log file with the server hostname

How do I do this?

Comment: I would probably write a script for it myself. Is that not an option?

Comment: I am doing that right now Bernhard. :) I was just hoping there was something like csshX for this also.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is trivial to do with a little script. For example:

```
for server in app0 app1 app4 app5 appN; do
    scp user@$server:/path/to/log/file /local/path/to/"$server"_file
done
```

The above will copy the file from each of the servers sequentially and name it `SERVERNAME_file`. So, the file from `app0` will be `app0_file` etc. You can obviously change the names to whatever you would like.

Comment: Put `&` at the end of the `scp` command and a `wait` at the end, and you have concurrency at no extra cost.

Comment: @l0b0 I don't know if that's desired. I like this approach because I can know if and which files failed to copy. Good tip though, thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Use [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/):

```
parallel -j0 scp {}:/remote_path file_from_{} ::: host1 host2 host3 # and so on
```

Unlike solutions that use a `for`, this will run all the downloads in parallel

Answer (score 5):

```
remote_path="/path/to/file"
local_target_dir="/path/to/dir"
hosts=(app00 app01)
for host in "${hosts[@]}"; do
    scp "$host":"$remote_path" "$local_target_dir"/filename."$host"
done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am new to bash programming and wrote something like that, just a lot dirtier. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use python, there is an interesting module that looks to simplify machine administration-ish tasks called fabric: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/tutorial.html

I have wanted to use it but have not got around too it

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
#!/bin/bash
#Expect script
/usr/bin/expect -<<EOD 

set SERVERS {1 2 3 .. N}

foreach SERVER \$SERVERS {
    spawn scp user@\$SERVER:remote local/"\$SERVER"RESWeb.log
    expect {
      -re ".*es.*o.*" {
        exp_send "yes\r"
        exp_continue
      }
      -re ".*sword.*" {
        exp_send "pswrd\r"
      }
    }
    expect eof 
}
EOD

echo "completed"
```